# Return a variable from my controller to a view using toRoute Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I am using Zend Framework 3 and I have a controller which routes to a view when `hasIdentity` is `true` (works)

How do I include a variable (e.g. `$myVar`) into the redirect so I can use it in my view?

```
if ($this->authService->hasIdentity()) {
    $myVar = "some data I want to pass to my view";
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('auth/welcome');
}
```

And how do I access that in my view?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

1. You can add it as query arguments in your redirect URL
   `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('auth/welcome', [
       'message' => 'some data I want to pass to my view',
   ]);`
2. You can store the value in session, redirect, retrieve from session and pass to the view.
3. Use flashMessenger view helper (extension of point 2).

Hope this works…